# Why it is possible to access views from a worker thread in Android 8.0?

Tags: android, multithreading

I know that it is illegal to access UI views from a worker thread. For example, my code below throws exception on `Android 4.4 (API 19)`: `android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException`: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

However, it works without exception on `Android 8.0 (API 26)` and successfully updates `TextView`.
The question is - why?

Maybe, it is allowed to access views from another thread in new Android versions?

```
public class TestActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button btnStart;
    private TextView txtInfo;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);

        txtInfo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtInfo);
        btnStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStart);

        btnStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override public void run() {
                        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                            try {
                                Thread.sleep(1000);
                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            txtInfo.setText(String.valueOf(i + 1));
                        }
                    }
                });
                t.start();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: In general, you can't update a widget from a background thread -- I have run into that crash on Android 9.0 a couple of times in the past week. Perhaps they added special support for `setText()` on a `TextView`, though I don't see anything in the source code.

Answer (score 0):

From [the post](https://medium.com/@dimezis/how-android-8-lets-you-get-away-with-touching-views-from-any-thread-906419b368fa)

> ```
> @Override
> public final void invalidateChild(View child, final Rect dirty) {
>     final AttachInfo attachInfo = mAttachInfo;
>     if (attachInfo != null && attachInfo.mHardwareAccelerated) {
>         // HW accelerated fast path
>         onDescendantInvalidated(child, child); // <-- does not have thread check
>         return;
>     }
>     // A bunch of code here for old slow path
>     parent.invalidateChildInParent(location, dirty); // <-- has thread check
> }
> ```

And it was fixed later: https://android-review.googlesource.com/c/platform/frameworks/base/+/937477